# How to disable collapsing top bar menu in zurb foundation?

Tags: menu, zurb-foundation

Is it possible to not have the top bar in Foundation to collapse to Menu and the three lines?  We don't really need this feature but not sure how to disable the collapse.

Will this require modifying the foundation.topbar.js?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I can't really understand what you are asking, is there any way you can clarify your question?  If possible include a link to a screenshot of what you want vs what is happening and we will see what we can do!  (As a [new user](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user) you can only include a max of 2 links in a post.)

Comment: Thanks Henrique!  

Sorry I wasn't clear enough.  I don't have any screenshots on me now but what I was basically trying to do with Foundation was to NOT have my buttons on the top right of the nav bar disappear when the width of the browser collapses to say tablet or mobile size.  We had sufficient width in the top bar even in mobile for the two buttons we wanted and it didn't make sense to collapse to a menu drop down as is the default in Foundation.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Foundation via sass, there's an even better way to go about it.
Just open up the _settings.scss file and find this line:

```
// $topbar-breakpoint: emCalc(940px); // Change to 9999px for always mobile layout
```

Uncomment it and change the value to 0, or whatever breaking point you would like to use.

Answer (score 2):

Things have changed in foundation 5.1.1 and this worked for me in the css:  changed

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) {
  .top-bar {
```

to

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 4.063em) {
  .top-bar {
```

Comment: @Vincent: 40.063em vs 4.063em

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to not show the default nav menu for small-screens with the menu toggle icon without modifying any js files. Foundation 4 uses a series of [visibility classes](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/visibility.html) to show and hide elements on the screen along with [media queries](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/media-queries.html).

As an example here's the main navigation for Zurb's demo site linked above:

```
<nav class="top-bar hide-for-small" style="">
  <ul class="title-area">
    <!-- Title Area -->
    <li class="name">
      <h1><a href="/">Foundation</a></h1>
    </li>
    <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
  </ul>


<section class="top-bar-section">
    <!-- Right Nav Section -->
    <ul class="right">
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li class=""><a href="/grid.php">Features</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li class=""><a href="/templates.php">Add-ons</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li class=""><a href="/case-jacquelinewest.php">Case Studies</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li class=""><a href="/docs/">Docs</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li class=""><a href="/training.php">Training</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li class="has-form">
        <a href="http://foundation.zurb.com/docs" class="button">Getting Started</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section></nav>
```

As you can see it's simple to remove the `.menu-icon` class or even the `li`; if you look at line 2816 of docs.css you can see that a minimum screen breakpoint (58.75em) is set for the `.top-bar` class:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 58.75em) {
.top-bar {
background: #111111;
*zoom: 1;
overflow: visible; }
.top-bar:before, .top-bar:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table; }
.top-bar:after {
  clear: both; }
.top-bar .toggle-topbar {
  display: none; }
.top-bar .title-area {
  float: left; }
.top-bar .name h1 a {
  width: auto; }
...
```

Since F4 is built with a mobile first design approach by default the menu is set for small screens. At a minimum width of 58.75 em, the breakpoint is set to modify the default `.top-bar` view for larger screens so that the menu `ul` is displayed inline and the child `li` are floated left.

You can override the `.top-bar` so that this is the default view by overriding the corresponding lines of css/scss or even the global variables.

Comment: Thanks for that tnog!  That actually helped.  What I was able to do eventually was something like this to make sure our sign up and sign in buttons showed up even past that minimum width of 58.75em
<code>
        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon">
               
            <a class="button" href="#" data-reveal-id="SignUp">Sign Up</a>

            <a class="button" href="#" data-reveal-id="LogIn">Log In</a>
        </li>

</code>

Sorry this is pretty terrible.  How do you get code to show up properly?

Answer (score 1):

If you're working directly with the Foundation CSS, you can override the mobile mode of the .top-bar menu by changing the breakpoints in the following lines of CSS to 0em:

```
.top-bar-js-breakpoint {
  width: 58.75em !important;
  visibility: hidden; }

.js-generated {
  display: block; }

@media only screen and (min-width: 58.75em) {
----- numerous lines below -------
```

However, if you're working with a child theme in WordPress or another CMS, you have to copy all of the .top-bar related selectors below the actual media query and paste them into your child CSS, then change the breakpoints to 0. Works like a charm.