# Zurb Foundation Disable Top-Bar Collapse

Tags: zurb-foundation

How can I disable the top-bar collapse for medium / small screens ?

I followed the instructions from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709326/zurb-foundation-top-bar-dont-collapse-to-menu) but no matter what I set the min-width to, I get the same result.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the SCSS version then you can modify the break point.

```
$topbar-breakpoint: emCalc(1px); /* Change to 9999px for always mobile layout */
$topbar-media-query: "only screen and (min-width: #{$topbar-breakpoint})";
```

Comment: Not using the SCSS version. I tried modifying the lines mentioned in the link post above (I think its effectively the same one you point to via scss) without any change in the functionality. The lines I modified were 3002. Thanks.

Comment: You can download a custom version with the breakpoint changed. You will see that as one of the options to modify before downloading here http://foundation.zurb.com/download.php#customizeFoundation

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate this is an old question but I came across this issue today and found something in the Foundation sites documentation. They have kindly created a mixin that will let you unstack the top bar which is much nicer!

Simply add the following to your SCSS code:

```
.element {
  @include top-bar-unstack;
}
```

If you are in a situation where you need to apply this to certain devices then you could always wrap this within a media query, again Foundation have a cool mixin for this too, for example:

```
.element {
  @include breakpoint(medium only) {
    @include top-bar-unstack;
  }
}
```

Bit of a rubbish scenario, but you get the idea

[See Foundation Docs](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/top-bar.html#top-bar-unstack)